# NULL appended to array passed to function

Tags: php, codeigniter, null

I'm getting an odd error when attemping to pass an array to a function which updates data in a MySQL table.

My trigger

```
$input_data = array(
  'field0' => 'abc',
  'field1' => '123'
);

// var dump #1
var_dump($input_data);
// gives expected result (2 element array)

$this->user->update_user_info($input_data);
```

User model

```
function update_user_info($new_data) {
    // var dump #2
    var_dump($new_data);

    // this gives:
    // array(2) {
    //    ["field0"] => string(3) "abc"
    //    ["field1"]=> string(3) "123"
    // }
    // NULL
}
```

Where is that ending NULL coming from?? I am trying to use this with Codeigniter's active Record Update class and it fails because of that NULL.

I've attempted to copy it to a new array by looping through a foreach, but the NULL value follows to the new array, even though it doesn't appear to be in the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you check this with `print_r($new_data)` ?

Comment: are you calling a model from any helper?

Comment: try `var_dump($new_data);die()` and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the above 'Answer', I'm new to the site and couldn't see the comment button :p

I've since solved this problem in terms of my own circumstances and possibly this may apply to you.

As I said earlier my problem was identical, the cause was not correctly returning both functions - I returned the secondary function i.e the one that my array was passed to like so.

```
function update_user_info($new_data) {

    // var dump #2
    var_dump($new_data);
    return;

}
```

but in the first function I was not returning after calling the second function, hope that makes sense and that this helps you too, it was frustrating as hell for me!

Answer (score 0):

The NULL is obviously not in the array; It is printed on a second call to update_user_info() function.  You should try to find out why the update_user_info() function is called twice.